# Cannot Authenticate to one VisualStudio.com TFS in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, authentication, tfs, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

I am running Visual Studio 2015. It is registered on my machine under my personal Microsoft account. Running on Windows 10 Professional.

I can connect to my personal tfs at visualstudio.com with no issue.

I can connect to a corporate tfs at visualstudio.com with no issue, under a second Microsoft (Office365) account.

I have a third corporate tfs at visualstudio.com that it refuses to connect to, which uses a third Microsoft (Office365) account. 
My corresponding MS account is actually the owner for this repository. 
I am able to login via the website without any issue (at  mycompany.visualstudio.com ).
Trying to login to this third one in Visual Studio however gives the error message:

[image]

I've double checked the url, double checked all my credentials. 
I've done the usual suspect fix of clearing all of IE's cache, and just for good measure, cleared all of Edge's cache too.

**UPDATE:** I've now tried removing all the accounts from the VS login dialog; and logged out of VS; and cleared IE cookies, and then logged back in and added all accounts as necessary, and still get this error, even though the web site works fine.

Comment: You are mixing your terms and need to be clear. There are two ways to configure security for VSTS. Microsoft Account (MSA) or Azure Active Directory (AAD). Can. You specify which you mean?

Comment: What does it say when you hit the Web UI?

Comment: As I stated in my question, they are both being connected to via Microsoft Accounts; one being my personal account, and the other two being corporate Microsoft accounts configured on each respective companies Office365. I am able to login via the website without any issue, at mycompany.visualstudio.com.

Comment: Wrong. If they are corporate "office365" accounts they are backed by AAD and have nothing to do with "Microsoft Accounts" which are for individuals and not companies. Your terms are being used incorrectly which makes your question confusing and imposible to answer.

Comment: Note: It is posible to add your Microsoft Account (MSA) as a Guest in your AAD Tennant and get access to VSTS logging in as your MSA.

Comment: The account you have grayed out bottom left of your connection box does not have permission to access that VSTS instance.

Comment: I was unaware of that. When logging in through either VS or the web they are both presented with exactly the same UI, so they appeared to be the same. As for the account... it is the same account which I can log in to the Web UI on the same company VS url blurred at the top, and I get no errors on the web site. When logged in on the web site I am able to make changes and perform all the normal function. But that SAME account on the SAME VS account fails in Visual Studio and gets told that it does not have permission.

Comment: @eidylon Do you mean it popup login window when connect to that VSTS instance and failed authenticate? Do you have this issue on another machine? Try to clear corresponding credential in Credential Manager.

Comment: Are you by any chance a "Stakeholder"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is actually a problem with VSTS. 
Other users are having the same problem. 
Bigger issue at play.

Answer (score 0):

The account that you are using does not have permission to access that account on VSTS. You should click the "change account" button in your screenshot and use an account that does have permission.

Note: Something that can be confusing is that you can have an MSA that is the same email as your corporate AAD account. This means that the email address can look like the right one, but may in fact not be. Try switching and loggin in again rather than picking from the list.

Comment: The account is able to log in to the web ui of mycompany.visualstudio.com and works fine, being able to upload files, delete files, rename files etc, and gets no permission errors. I ***had*** accidentally set up a personal account that was the same email as the problem corporate account, as you mentioned. I've since figured out how to change the email address on that personal account, and so have eliminated that point of confusion. The corporate account still does not work in Visual Studio though, despite working fine in the web ui.

Comment: Is your corporate account listed as a "Stakeholder"? As they are not allowed to use VS for licencing reasons.

Comment: Nope; listed as a Basic user (we do have one other user who is a SH). And I saw it somewhere the other day (but can't find it now), but my account is actually the owner account of the repo.

Comment: Then the identity that is being used is not correct. You may need to completely log out of Visual Studio, and then login only with your corporate creds to test.

Comment: I've now tried removing all the accounts from the VS login dialog; and logged out of VS; and cleared IE cookies, and then logged back in and added all accounts as necessary, and still get this error, even though the web site works fine.

Comment: Yup, that's where I'm at now. Hopefully they'll have a resolution, and I'll come back and post it. Worst to worst, I guess the last resort will be uninstalling VS entirely and reinstalling, and hope that works. And I guess the nuclear option would be to rebuild my whole machine. Here's hoping it doesn't come to that!!!