# To access a VisualStudio.com account, log in using the picker above

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

When i am trying to add TFS server, i got the warring message "To access a VisualStudio.com account, log in using the picker above" as shown in the following screen shot. Could anyone suggest me how i can solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: And what is your question, please?

Comment: How can i solve this issue?

Comment: What issue? It is not at all clear what your problem is: is your VisualStudio.com account being rejected? You don't want to log in? Or what?

Comment: actually when i m trying to add my TFS Server url then this error messages shown, but i have already signed with my valid account on VisualStudio.com. After this warning i am not able to add my TFS server url.

Comment: Searching for the error message, [I see this similar question](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/51616/to-access-a-visualstudiocom-account-log-in-using-t.html) - is that any use to you? I've also added a possible dup from here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot Authenticate to one VisualStudio.com TFS in Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40940764/cannot-authenticate-to-one-visualstudio-com-tfs-in-visual-studio-2015)

Comment: I got this after I tried accessing a renamed organization. But when I used the old name it worked. weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to connect to VSTS(https://xxxxxx.visualstudio.com), click the drop-down list and then "Add an account", sign in with the account that you use to connect to VSTS. It will list the VSTS Accounts you have access and then you just need to double click on the account to connect to it.[image]

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I select my account and nothing happens.

Answer (score 5):

```
This is how i solved the issue, may be it will help you.
Here are the steps

     1. Login to **VSTS(Visual studio team services account)** or  from 
    account you have loggedin visual studio in web browser (e.g chrome, IE etc)
     2. Then close visual studio and again open it. No add url **(yourorgname.visualstudio.com)** to Team services in team explorer it will work like a charm.

Note: i am using VS2019
```

I think this is the "first time" connect issue.
If you have the required permissions to connect, then follow this solution. It worked for me.
Close the Visual Studio.
When you are inside your organization network, simply using any browser, go to https://dev.azure.com/YourOrganizationServer. You will be redirected to the Azure DevOps website and will see your projects.
Now open the Visual Studio, try the connection manager. 
You will see the TFS server name and projects under the dropdown menu.
I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you Hanif. I just restarted my VS Code 2019 and it then worked just fine. Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem as OP, which is that the server could not be added and connected to because the message "To access a xxx account, log in using the picker above" did not go away even though an account was selected from the drop down and I even double clicked the account again as suggested by another answer. I already had the account—that I wanted to use to connect—selected in the drop down and could select it. However, this message stayed as if the account was rejected or just not selected at all.

Following worked for me to be able to select and account, add the server and then connect to it. It seems the authentication did not work because of something cached from the Identity Service.

1. Close all instances of your Visual Studio
2. Go to the folder %localappdata%\.identityservice and delete all files inside this folder. I made a backup of all files before deleting them, just to be sure
3. Start Visual Studio again and try to add the server and pick the account again

**I had to do these steps twice, maybe try it a few times if it does not work the first time.**

Comment: Worked first try for me

Comment: Worked for me in first time. Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to configure Visual Studio to use the system browser instead of the embedded browser. Here is what I did:

1. Go to Tools / Options / Environment / Accounts
2. Look for the option 'add and reauthenticate accounts using:'
3. Select 'System web browser'
4. OK
5. Go back to the 'Connect to a Project' dialog
6. From the dropdown, select 'Add an account...'
7. Your browser should open, then connect to your account
8. Go back to the 'Connect to a Project' dialog and click 'Refresh'
9. After that I can see my DevOps from the list

Note that once my account was added, I put back the 'Embedded web browser' option after that because it is more convenient and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Note: If all the above Methods didn't work , then do a **restart of your VDI** *(if applicable)* and check . In my case this happened because there was a Firewall changes happened and we had to restart VDI's to have the changes effected.